# Problem with applying socks proxy systemwide

Tags: ssh

i trying tunnel my traffic through SSH server. when i use Firefox network setting, it work well but when i try apply the socks proxy system wide from ubuntu setting and tunnel google-chrome traffic, it just don't work. i guess problem is ubuntu proxy tool apply socks proxy even for terminal which cause SSH connection fail because proxy is something like 127.0.0.1:1194

how to fix it on ubuntu 12.4 ?